# Loop which sends commands via COM port to syringe pump stops sending commands after some time

Tags: python, arrays, serial-port, infinite-loop

I have created this code to communicate with a syringe pump. Everything is working fine, but I need this to run for hours on end, and it keeps stopping at what seems like the same time every time (I have not timed how long it takes or counted the number of iterations, it runs for approx. 30-60min). If someone doesn't mind taking a look and letting me know what could be causing this. I am not very experienced with python.

I think it is worth noting that when the code "stops", the kernel is still running and the COM port is still open. It isn't breaking the loop when it stops, it just sends a 0mL/min flow rate command and that is it.
Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import serial
import time
import math

#connect to serial port
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM3'
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = 1
ser.xonxoff = 0
ser.rtscts = 0
ser.dsrdtr = 0
ser.close()
ser.open()
ser.timeout = 1

# number of steps in one cycle
steps_per_cycle = 20


#variables
A     = 1 #peak to peak displacement of piston
omega = 1 #frequency
a     = 1 #tube inner radius

#volume functions
pump_rates = 0.5 * (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(steps_per_cycle) / steps_per_cycle)) # generate sinusoidal pump rates
pump_rates0 = 0.5 * A * omega * np.pi * (a**2) * np.cos(omega*np.arange(steps_per_cycle) / steps_per_cycle) #Harris and Goren Flow Rate fxn

#command loop
if ser.isOpen():
    try:
        i = 0
        while i<=2: #infinite loop
                print(ser.name + ' is open...') 
                for rate in pump_rates:
                    if rate > 0:                          #infusing
                        cmd = f'irate {"%.5f" % rate} ml/min'  
                        print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        # ser.write(cmd.encode())
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        
                        cmd = f'irun'
                        # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        
                        cmd = f'ctime'
                        # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))  
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if rate < 0:                              #withdrawing
                        cmd = f'wrate {"%.5f" % -rate} ml/min'  
                        print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        # ser.write(cmd.encode())
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        
                        cmd = f'wrun'
                        # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        
                        cmd = f'ctime'
                        # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        time.sleep(1)
                    if rate == 0:
                        cmd = f'stop'
                        print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                        ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                        ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                        ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        
    # except ser.SerialException as e:
    #     print("Serial port error: " + str(e))
    finally:
        if ser.isOpen():
            ser.close()
```

At first, I had a massive array with repeating values that would be periodically sent to the COM port, but that was clunky and I was running out of memory so I made an infinite loop. I don't know why it is stopping.

Comment: Do you get any errors when your code stops executing? Also aside from that I would recommend creating some functions it looks like you could reuse stuff and make your code shorter which will be also easier to debug

Comment: Also, how do you execute your code? Are you running it directly from an IDE or directly from terminal?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when it stops. I have been running it in Spyder. I just thought to run it in Python (terminal) after I made the post so I am trying that now..it has been running for about 20min. Does the console in Spyder have a limit for how many commands it can send or how many previous commands it can display? Thank you for the response.

Comment: I am not sure if Spyder has as limit or not, but since you are not seeing any errors it might be an issue with Spyder, lets see if running directly from console works!

Comment: I just came back to it and it had stopped again. No errors on it again, I was really thinking that would work!

Comment: can you uncomment the excep part and make it more general, something like: `except Exception as e: print(e)` maybe that will give you something

Comment: I uncommented that section and I changed the loop a bit so it opens and closes the port after every cycle, maybe that will help. I am recording how long it runs from now on so I can get an idea if it is a fixed amount or random.

Answer (score 0):

It has been running for over 2 hours which is definitely more than it was before so I will call the problem solved. I changed the code to close and open the serial port at the end of each loop. If someone can explain why this solved the issue I would appreciate it. Attached is the edited part of the code:

```
try:
i = 0
while i<=1: #infinite loop
            
            print(ser.name + ' is open...') 
            for rate in pump_rates:
                if rate > 0:                          #infusing
                    cmd = f'irate {"%.5f" % rate} ml/min'  
                    print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    # ser.write(cmd.encode())
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    
                    cmd = f'irun'
                    # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    
                    cmd = f'ctime'
                    # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))  
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    time.sleep(1)
                if rate < 0:                              #withdrawing
                    cmd = f'wrate {"%.5f" % -rate} ml/min'  
                    print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    # ser.write(cmd.encode())
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    
                    cmd = f'wrun'
                    # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    
                    cmd = f'ctime'
                    # print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    time.sleep(1)
                if rate == 0:
                    cmd = f'stop'
                    print(f'Sending command: {cmd}')
                    ser.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
                    ser.write(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))
                    ser.write(str.encode(cmd + '\r\n'))
                    time.sleep(1)
                    
                    ser.close()
                    ser.open()   
    except ser.SerialException as e:
    print("Serial port error: " + str(e))
```